# Problem proving a trigonometric result.

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

**Question**: If $\frac{\tan(\theta-\phi)}{\tan\theta}+\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\theta}=1$, show that $\tan\theta\tan\phi=\tan^2\alpha$.

**My attempt**:

$\frac{\tan(\theta-\phi)}{\tan\theta}+\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\theta}=1$

$\implies\frac{\frac{\sin(\theta-\phi)}{\cos(\theta-\phi)}}{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}+\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\theta}=1$

$\implies\frac{\frac{\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\theta\sin\phi}{\cos\theta\cos\phi+\sin\theta\sin\phi}}{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}+\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\theta}=1$

$\implies\frac{\cos\theta(\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\theta\sin\phi)}{\sin\theta(\cos\theta\cos\phi+\sin\theta\sin\phi)}+\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\theta}=1$

**My problem**: I am unable to figure out how to proceed further. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\sin^2\theta}=1-\dfrac{\tan(\theta-\phi)}{\tan\theta}=\dfrac{\sin\{\theta-(\theta-\phi)\}}{\cos(\theta-\phi)\sin\theta}=?$$

$$\implies\sin^2\alpha=\dfrac{\sin\theta\sin\phi}{\cos(\theta-\phi)}$$

$$\cos^2\alpha=?$$

$$\text{Now, }\tan\alpha=\dfrac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}$$

Comment: How did you get $1-\dfrac{\tan(\theta-\phi)}{\tan\theta}=\dfrac{\sin\{\theta-(\theta-\phi)\}}{\cos(\theta-\phi)\sin\theta}$

Comment: @MrAP, Write both $\tan$ as $$\dfrac{\sin}{\cos}$$

Comment: I had done that and simplified before asking but could not get there..

Comment: @MrAP, We have $$\sin^2\alpha=\dfrac{\sin\theta\sin\phi}{\cos(\theta-\phi)}$$

$$\implies\csc^2\alpha=\dfrac{\cos(\theta-\phi)}{\sin\theta\sin\phi}=\cot\theta\cot\phi+1$$
$$\iff\tan\theta\tan\phi=\dfrac1{\csc^2\alpha-1}=?$$

Answer (score 1):

The condition gives $$\sin^2\alpha=\sin^2\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta\tan(\theta-\phi)$$ and since $$\tan^2\alpha=\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{1-\sin^2\alpha},$$ we need to prove that
$$\tan\theta\tan\phi=\frac{\sin^2\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta\tan(\theta-\phi)}{1-\sin^2\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta\tan(\theta-\phi)}$$ or
$$\tan\phi=\frac{\sin\theta-\cos\theta\tan(\theta-\phi)}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta\tan(\theta-\phi)}$$ or
$$\tan\phi=\frac{\tan\theta-\tan(\theta-\phi)}{1+\tan\theta\tan(\theta-\phi)},$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Put $\tan (\theta)=a,\tan (\phi)=b,\tan (\alpha)=c $ . And use $\tan (x-y)=\frac {\tan (x)-\tan (y)}{1+\tan (x)\tan (y)} $ so we have $\frac {a-b}{a (1+ab)}+\frac {(1+a^2)c^2}{(1+c^2)a^2}=1$ cross multilplying and simplifying we have $a^2+a^2c^2-ab-abc^2+c^2+a^2c^2+abc^2+a^3bc^2=a^2+a^2c^2+a^3bc^2+a^3b$ cancelling out we have $c^2 (1+a^2)=ab (1+a^2) $ as $a\in R $ so we can cancel $1+a^2$ thus $c^2=ab $